# How can I import python Int16 to PostgreSQL as smallint?

Tags: pandas, database, postgresql, psycopg2, sqldatatypes

I am using `psycopg2` in python to import a `pandas` dataframe to a `PostgreSQL` database. Elements of several columns in the dataframe are of type `<class 'numpy.int16'>`. I do the import like this:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, method='multi', if_exists=if_exists_opt_loc, index=False)
```

After this write, I see that the columns in the database have type `bigint`, while only a `smallint` is needed to store the `Int16` values.

How can do the import so that the columns have type `smallint`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the dtype parameter too:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

```
dtype={'datefld': sqlalchemy.DateTime(), 
                             'intfld':  sqlalchemy.types.SmallInteger(),
                             'strfld': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=255)
                             'floatfld': sqlalchemy.types.Float(precision=3,asdecimal=True)
                             'booleanfld': sqlalchemy.types.Boolean})
```

Comment: I guess I totally missed the `dtype` parameter. Thanks!